Taylor Swift - Use of "them" in her text "she fights for the rights and causes I believe need a warrior to champion them"
Three hours ago, Taylor Swift posted on Instagram, which includes the following sentence:

I’m voting for @kamalaharris because she fights for the rights and causes I believe need a warrior to champion them.

I've seen people argue about whether the use of "them" at the end is grammatically correct. Some feel like it's better to say "... for the rights and causes I believe need a warrior to champion".
Can anyone here help? Which expression is correct?

It is redundant. But that's colloquial internet language, where everything is permitted.

I don't find it redundant. Without them it could theoretically mean "a warrior for them to champion".

champion is a transitive verb there and wants an object, which is duly supplied. It's a perfectly grammatical sentence.

I'm sure this has been asked before about something other than a Taylor Swift tweet, but good luck trying to find it! I Such usages were maybe more common in the past, and some languages routinely do this in relative clauses.

At any rate, it's awkward and could be improved by providing a (redundant) antecedent in the relative clause. "... she fights for [important] rights and causes - the ones I believe need a warrior to champion them."

The 'them' refers to the 'rights and causes' that exist out there, without it at the end it feels like you are missing something.

"The causes need a warrior to champion them" feels perfectly normal to me, but the intermediate "[that] I believe" makes it suddenly sound awkward. I'm not sure why. "The causes, I believe, need a warrior to champion them" also feels smooth, yet "the causes I believe need a warrior to champion them" does not. "The causes that I believe are in need of a warrior to champion them" feels good too. Perhaps the awkwardness is mostly psychological: if anyone can explain my intuitive feelings here, please let me know

Welcome to ELU! While interesting, this question does not show any research effort. Someone, ideally user104, please edit to include at least a description of who is arguing over this. If it is on a social media platform, copy the relevant counter-claim to avoid link-rot.

Quick reminder that this question is about grammar, not politics. Let's not go off-topic.

Antipodean. NZ. (Usually) closer to the King's Engrish than is USAian :-).|| I'd prefer "which I believe" or "that I believe". But as is it scans OK.  (Is grokable:-) ).

@Eth - I wasn't saying that 'a warrior for them to champion' had any particular meaning, just that the syntax of what Ms Swift wrote was made clearer by the addition of 'them', and therefore I didn't consider it to be redundant.

Can you Post three or four examples where you've seen people argue that?

Usually a relative clause has a gap in it which corresponds to the noun  phrase that it is modifying:

That is the dog(i) who  [ __(i) bit him ].
That is the dog(i) who [ he bit __(i) ].

The little subscript '(i)'s show that the dog and the gap have the same identity; they refer to the same thing. In (1) and (2) the gap in the relative clauses represents the dog. Where that gap appears changes the meaning of the relative clause. In (1) the gap tells us that the dog bit the man. In (2) the gap tells us the the man bit the dog. We could model the sentences like this:

That is the dog who[ the dog bit him ].
That is the dog who [ he bit the dog].

Here is Taylor Swift's perfectly grammatical sentence modelled the same way:

I'm voting for Kamala Harris because she fights for the rights and causes(i) [I believe  __(i) need a warrior to champion them ]
I'm voting for Kamala Harris because she fights for the rights and causes [I believe  the rights and causes need a warrior to champion them]

If you take out the word them it changes the meaning. Consider:

The rights and causes need a warrior to champion.

This would mean that the rights and causes championed the warrior!?? Not what we want at all!
I'm not a Swiftie, but she knows her grammar!

Lucid. Thank you. I think the grammar you recommend hardly bothers about such trivialities as "who vs whom ("the dog who he bit")— a big deal for some people. Just asking although it's beside the point here.

@user405662 Good question. Yes, whom is grammatical there but not necessary. I opted for who because it keeps the bit before the brackets the same in the two examples.

Who/whom would not be a question if the examples were about "the dog that ...".

@Araucaria-Him Very clear explanation, but shouldn’t the boldface in the examples also include the articles: i.e, “the dog” and “the rights and causes”?

@KrisW From the semantics of the relative clause itself, you'd think so, as the gap functions a bit like a referring pronoun (and so is definite in flavour). However, the syntax tells us that the relative clause is attached to the nominal (ie the chunk after the determiner, in this case the word dog) and that the definite article before dog actually scopes over the whole noun +relative clause. So the structure's actually [ the [dog who bit the man]]. There's no easy answer for how best to represent the semantics of the gap-antecedent relationship and the grammar at the same time. (shrugs)

Araucaria's answer, though mostly accurate, is missing a crucial point that explains why the version of the sentence without the "them" is, in fact, also correct. (I agree with the commenters cited by the OP that the version without the "them" sounds better than the one Taylor tweeted, so apparently I'm not alone in considering it correct.)
Specifically: that version contains a parasitic gap (see Huddleston & Pullum (2002), p. 1095).
To borrow Huddleston & Pullum's example, consider these two sentences:

They do an annual report that I always throw away without reading it.
They do an annual report that I always throw away without reading.

These two sentences mean the same thing, and both are grammatical albeit somewhat awkward. The difference between them is that, while the relative clause in the (1) contains only an ordinary gap (which we interpret as referring to the annual report), the relative clause in (2) contains an extra "parasitic" gap also:

They do an annual report that [ I always throw ___ away without reading it ].
They do an annual report that [ I always throw ___ away without reading ___ ].

A relative clause with a parasitic gap is unusual because the clause becomes ungrammatical, or at least ends up having a different interpretation, if you fill in the antecedent gap but leave the parasitic gap in place:

I always throw their annual report away without reading it.
* I always throw their annual report away without reading.

(Strictly speaking, (4) technically is grammatical if you interpret read as intransitive, but that would be a fairly odd reading.)
Now, if we consider the case of Taylor Swift's sentence and the proposed variant without the them, we see that the same phenomenon occurs:

She fights for the rights and causes [ I believe ___ need a warrior to champion them ].
She fights for the rights and causes [ I believe ___ need a warrior to champion ___ ].

Both (5) and (6) are correct, just as with (1) and (2) above.
Now Araucaria notes that, if you try to fill the gap in the relative clauses in (5) and (6), the second one becomes ungrammatical, or at least means something quite unusual:

I believe these rights and causes need a warrior to champion them.
* I believe these rights and causes need a warrior to champion.

But this does not mean that (6) is also incorrect--just like how the fact that (4) is incorrect does not mean that (2) is incorrect. As stated above, all sentences with parasitic gaps become ungrammatical, or require a different interpretation, if you fill in the gap acting as the antecedent but leave the parasitic gap in place.
In short: both versions--the one with the them and the one without it--are correct. That said, as with (1) and (2) above, both (5) and (6) sound rather awkward, which is likely why those commenters online are debating which version sounds best.

A parasitic gap cannot just be a gap that has another gap before it. They are, as implied by H&P, of limited acceptability occurring in only a limited range of environments. They state that "The most clearly acceptable cases of parasitic gaps occur ... in non-finite clauses functioning as adjuncts in clause structure". This is emphatically not the case here where the gap is occurring in what would be the catenative complement of the verb need in the original example.

Another thing which increases the likelihood that of acceptability is both gaps having the same grammatical relations  in their respective clauses. Again, not the case here. Lastly, I point you to the fact that for both Kate Bunting and I (and I think from comments,  for Janus) OP's suggested version is either ungrammatical or has a completely different meaning. I believe that it's  the acceptability of the version with the different meaning which is leading you do trust the version with the missing object.

@Araucaria-Him Maybe it's just me, but I agree with the commenters cited by the OP claiming that (6) sounds better than (5) and that both mean the same thing.

Completely doesn't and can't work for me. Perhaps there's a pondian split here given the me/Kate/Janus grammaticality judgement (though I doubt it). Maybe check in Chat? Signing off ... Ciao  Raccoon.

Ok, so before I actually go, how's this for you: "I found this raccoon I believe needs a human to house" <-- If that ain't no good, why the racoon not?

@Araucaria-Him A question: what do you think of the example "Which students did you persuade to invite us to come and see?" To me that sounds fine (with the gaps being the objects of persuade and come and see), but this paper puts it at the end of a list of examples of "decreasing acceptability" (p. 11).

When you lightly skim it, at first blush  it goes down ok. But then if you pay attention to who's doing the inviting and who's being invited it no longer works and just kinda falls flabbily apart.

I also find it impossible for the coreferential gap to live where you put it in 5 and 6, hence them can't be gapped like that. She fights for the rights and causes [ ___ I believe need a warrior to champion ___ ]. Gaps between believe and need would be verbal - {[rights and causes][that] I believe [are in] need [of] a warrior to champion them.}

You can sometimes put some objects in the middle of a concatenated verb, but for me, you can't do it here. Mostly, it happens with pronouns that specify the actor. They create a specific instance of a general case. I regarded leaving the party so early as rude. I regarded her leaving the party so early as rude.

@Araucaria-Him Huh. To me that example sounds perfectly fine however many times I read it closely; the structure "did you persuade ___ [ to invite us [ to come and see ___ ] ]" seems obvious. I suspect that most speakers who accept that sentence will also accept "the rights and causes [ I believe [ ___  need a warrior [ to champion ___ ] ] ]," though the two aren't really parallel.

@alphabet If that is the case (it's not for me), I see no reason why a subordinate relative clause and matrix interrogative should behave in the same way, given that they have quite different grammatical rules. [And in your case the two gaps do have the same syntactic function within their respective clauses.] In addition there's no alternative meaning available/preferred in your suggested example.

@alphabet If the omission of OP's them is possible only because it's a parasitic gap, what do you think about this sentence from a 1987 WESTCHESTER OPINION article of the New York Times? Some furniture needs two people to lift and carry. https://www.nytimes.com/1987/05/31/nyregion/westchester-opinion-the-lost-and-found-department.html Clearly, the gap after carry is not a parasitic gap. The gaps after lift and carry would be across-the-board gaps in CGEL. This means that these variations also work: Some furniture needs two people to lift. Some furniture needs two people to carry.

@alphabet According to the 1983 paper you cited in the comment, if OP's them can be left out, it's not because the position of the omitted them is a parasitic gap. The paper has this restriction: (64) A parasitic gap may not be c-commanded by the real gap. In the version of OP without them, the second gap is c-commanded by the first gap: ... she fights for the rights and causes I believe [___ need a warrior [to champion ___ ]]. So the second gap cannot be a parasitic gap. Now if you can omit them, then you should look for some other reason than a parasitic gap.


I’m voting for @kamalaharris because she fights for the rights and causes I believe need a warrior to champion them.

Simplifying the sentence and making the connections more obvious, as well as making the talk  about the sentence easier, gives the grammatically equivalent sentence below.

I’m voting for X because she fights for causes that  need a warrior to champion them.

"That" is the relative subject pronoun, replacing "causes" in the relative clause, and "causes" is effectively the subject of "need" by the bias of using "that"; the syntax in the clause should be respected, and  this would not be achieved by "the causes need a warrior to champion" because there is no object for "champion", which is a transitive verb; also the object could be anything, for instance, we could have "the causes need a warrior to champion the recent ideas that they foster", and this sounds quite correct. Only by using "them" can it be made unmistakable that what is to be championed are the causes. Therefore, "them" is necessary.
Addition Precisions of which I should perhaps not have assumed that they went without saying
I assumed that "I believe" is a comment clause (making a comment on the clause in which it is inserted), that is,  a parenthetical disjunct (CoGEL); it should in fact appear between commas, and that is not the case in the OP's sentence, but I made the assumption that the commas had been omitted in the OP's sentence—because it is not so obvious (especially as you pass from speech to writing) that they are rather necessary. This is why I got rid of this part in the simplification (optional adverbial).
CoGEL: Comment clauses, many of which are characteristic of spoken English, are generally marked prosodically by increased speed and lowered volume.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

This seems to be a political question. To me, this sentence is absolutely fine, and I cannot understand how anyone could doubt that. And I would bet that she employs a secretary who will check all written statements she makes and fixes them if needed.
You need a warrior who champions these causes.  Shortened to “you need a warrior who champions them” shortened further to her sentence.

It is ungrammatical. Here's the clause in question:

...she fights for the rights and causes [I believe ____ need a warrior to champion them].

The bracketed clause is a bare relative clause without any relative word. The relative clause has a gap, which functions as the subject of need a warrior to champion them. So the question boils down to the following simpler clause and whether you need them at the end or not:

(1) the rights and causes need a warrior to champion (them)

Here, them needs to go because the rights and causes has already been mentioned as subject.
If we use it as the subject then you can keep the object:

(2) it needs a warrior to champion the rights and causes

But being in a rather complex construction, even a native speaker can get confused.
EDIT
IF by (1) the writer had meant "the rights and causes require that a warrior champion them", them would have been necessary in (1), but I don't think that's what she meant.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
